# How to delete multiple value from matrix numpy low computational cost

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I've recently been trying my hand at numpy, and I'm trying to find a solution to **delete** the **elements** inside the **matrix** at **column 2** equal to the value stored in the variable **element**.
Since I am a large amount of data I would need to know if there was a more **efficient method** which takes **less time to execute** than the classic for.
I enclose an example:

```
element = [ 85.,  222., 166., 238.]

matrix = [[228.,   1., 222.],
          [140.,   0.,  85.],
          [140.,   0., 104.],
          [230.,   0., 217.],
          [115.,   1., 250.],
          [12.,    1., 166.],
          [181.,   1., 238.]]
```

the output:

```
matrix = [[140.,   0., 104.],
          [230.,   0., 217.],
          [115.,   1., 250.]]
```

The method I used is the following:

```
for y in element:
    matrix = matrix[(matrix[:,2]!= y)]
```

When running it for a large amount of data it takes a long time. Is there anything more efficient, so that you can save on execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`, I'd assume `matrix` is a numpy array. With that, you can use `np.isin` for your purpose:

```
matrix = np.array(matrix)

matrix[~np.isin(np.array(matrix)[:,2], element)]
```

Output:

```
array([[140.,   0., 104.],
       [230.,   0., 217.],
       [115.,   1., 250.]])
```

Comment: Thanks it's much better now, you have been so helpful to me.
But could I add descending sorting to this function?